# How to pop elemens from python list using loop?

Tags: python

I want to pop elements using for loop to take an index of elements and pop those elements from another list. I have a code but it gives an error 'index out of bound' when pop last elements

```
indice = [2, 5, 6]

listtopop = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in indice:

    listtopop.pop(i)
  
print(listtopop)
```

Comment: What is the real problem you're facing? What output do you expect?

Comment: Most importantly, let's say you have `indice = [1, 2, 3]`, would you expect the same or a different result if you instead have `indice = [3, 2, 1]`?

Comment: After popping the first two elements, there are now only 5 elements in the list. There is no index 6 anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pop elements from the list, the list is getting shorter and the indices are changing.

One way to do this, is to start popping the indices in reverse-sorted order (starting with the biggest number):

```
indice = [2, 5, 6]

listtopop = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in sorted(indice, reverse=True):
    listtopop.pop(i)

print(listtopop)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This almost always sounds like the wrong way of solving it

Comment: wait a second let me try this hope it works

Comment: o really this worked thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this isn't working is because as you pop items from the list, the list size decreases. Lets break it down into steps.

Step 1 in the for loop: `listtopop.pop(2)` in English remove the 3rd item

After Step 1 you are left with [1,4,6,7,8,9]

Step 2 in the for loop: `listtopop.pop(5)` in English remove the 6th item

After Step 2 you are left with [1,4,6,7,8]

Step 3 in the for loop: `listtopop.pop(6)` in English remove the 7th item.

Hang on! We only 5 items left in our list. Thus we cannot remove the 7th item, hence the error.
The best way to do this request would be to change the order of the 'indice' list to a descending order (where the highest number comes first and then second highest and so on). i.e [6,5,2].
Thank you.

Comment: yeah I was aware of the reason but  having a problem to solve this thank you all guys

Comment: all good, best of luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

Make a set out of `indice`, `indice = set(indice)`, then make *a new list* using:

```
indice = set(indice)

listtopop = [e for i, e in enumerate(listtopop) if i not in indice]
```

This will also be efficient, and linear time instead of polynomial...